# XQuery to show TITLE order by Different categories ORDER BY year

Tags: xml, xquery

I have been given an example here:[xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmvhv.jpg)

As you can see, there are different categories, which are mastersthesis and article.
I am asked to show all TITLE ORDERED BY year

I have this xquery so far but no luck...

For $x in doc("dblp.xml")/dblp

Order by $x /year   <---This is order the result by year-->

Return $x /title  <-- This is return the result with title only-->

However, I can only got the original result...may you please point out which parts are wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to select `for $x in doc("dblp.xml")/dblp/*` or `for $x in doc("dblp.xml")/dblp/(masterthesis, article)`.

Comment: Thanks you are the man! It works! If I want to RETURN both title and year(in a correct sort), is it possible?

Comment: Well, start with a tutorial on XPath and XQuery and experiment with an implementation and you should have no need to ask such "is is possible" questions. If I have shown you `dblp/(masterthesis, article)` then trying `$x/(title, year)` should be a possible experiment for you https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgCcow.